# How to prevent attributes inside a div to use css of project

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I would like to add a custom style or CSS to my Angular website elements without accessing the styles on the server or in another word how can I prevent the automatic access from global classes.

For example

```
<p>Something</p>
```

for the whole project the common CSS has been used. How can I prevent in order to use custom CSS. I am using it in Angular by having div with inner HTML styles.

Comment: Load the"some html" within a Iframe or else add a specific class to your parent element (which contains your dynamic content from some server) and inherit all the properties (which is bit big work).

Comment: Surely you would need some styling on it or are you just wanting to revert it to browser default?  In either case you would need to add a class and reset / revert / unset the styles that you don't want.  This may be helpful for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

Comment: You say CSS yet include none, please add more clarity to your question

Comment: @Pete  To bad that has such a low support level for this case

Comment: hmmm yeah, probably better trying with initial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial